# Setting up Geoserver GWC with ArcGIS compact cache layer

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, geowebcache, cache, tilecache

I have a huge problem setting up geoserver's geowebcache to serve [arcgis compact cache](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/27/introducing-the-compact-cache-storage-format/) layer and I am getting a bit confused. I have installed geoserver 2.8.0 which contains geowebcache 1.8.0.

According to official geowebcache manpage (http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.8.0/configuration/layers/arcgistilingschemes.html), serving of arcgis compact cache is not possible.

On the other hand, I have found this thread (http://sourceforge.net/p/geowebcache/mailman/message/31884822/) which says that it is possible to serve this data source. I have also found ArcGIS compact cache support in geowebcache RELEASE_NOTES.txt file on github under version 1.6.x. I can also see some code that should cope with arcgis compact cache in the git directories.

I tried to add following section to the `geowebcache.xml`:

```
<arcgisLayer>
      <name>naturalearth</name>
      <tilingScheme>/home/geoserver/geoserver2.8/data_dir/gwc/arccache/conf.xml</tilingScheme>
</arcgisLayer>
```

But geoserver failed to start.

If you can successfully serve arcgis compact cache, can you share the information about how to configure such a service with geowebcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to serve arcgis compact cache with geowebcache. The problem was in poor documentation.

Note that you can not publish arcgis compact cache with geoserver built in geowebcache, but you have to use standalone geowebcache application.

Then you just have to set up GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR context parameter and edit geowebcache.xml.

Now everything works fine for me,
(tested with ubuntu 14.04 LTS, tomact7 and geowebcache 1.8.0)

Answer (score 1):

As MilanMuňko has already pointed out, you'll have to use the [standalone geowebcache](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geowebcache/) to publish [ArcGIS compact cache](https://github.com/Esri/raster-tiles-compactcache).

Your ArcGIS compact cache folder must include `conf.xml` and `conf.cdi`, and an `_allLayers` folder.

To add the ArcGIS compact cache layer, edit `geowebcache.xml` (you can locate this file by visiting `http://localhost:8080/geowebcache` then look at the bottom of the web page) by adding a `arcgisLayer` tag inside `gwcConfiguration > layers` with a `tilingScheme` tag pointed to `conf.xml` then reload the configuration:

```
<gwcConfiguration>
  <gridSets>
    ...
  </gridSets>
  <layers>
    <wmsLayer>...</wmsLayer>
      ...
    <arcgisLayer>
      <name>sample_cache</name>
      <tilingScheme>/usr/local/tomcat/temp/geowebcache/sample_cache/conf.xml</tilingScheme>
    </arcgisLayer>
  </layers>
</gwcConfiguration>
```

For more information, please visit the [documentation](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/arcgistilingschemes.html).

Currently, this feature is fully usable in version 1.8.x - 1.10.5, partially usable (unable to preview the layer with built-in OpenLayers) in version 1.11.4 - 1.12.5 and broken in version 1.13.2 - 1.14.2.