# Loading Legend into standalone GWC with ArcGIS compact cache layer

Tags: legend, geowebcache, cache, tilecache, getlegendgraphic

I managed to load compact cache v2 into standalone GWC using information from [Setting up Geoserver GWC with ArcGIS compact cache layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167444/setting-up-geoserver-gwc-with-arcgis-compact-cache-layer). Example of my `<arcgisLayer>` in geowebcache.xml :

```
      :
      :
    <arcgisLayer>
      <name>Fluvial__20_1000_years__v2</name>
      <gridSubsets/>
      <expireCacheList>
        <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="-2"/>
      </expireCacheList>
      <expireClientsList>
        <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="7200"/>
      </expireClientsList>
      <backendTimeout>120</backendTimeout>
      <cacheBypassAllowed>false</cacheBypassAllowed>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <tilingScheme>e:\RBK\Fluvial__20_1000_years__v2\conf.xml</tilingScheme>
      <hexZoom>false</hexZoom>
      <storageFormat>esriMapCacheStorageModeCompactV2</storageFormat>
    </arcgisLayer>
  </layers>
</gwcConfiguration>
```

Example of functional WMTS in QGIS:
[image]
Compact cache v2 from ArcGIS creates .json subfiles (root.json and iteminfo.json), based on root.json I created conf.xml (which is needed to load the cache into WMTS in standalone GWC) see `<tilingScheme>` in geowebcache.xml example.

My question is, in root.json there is also legend info, is there any way to add this legend to WMTS in standalone GWC ?

```
  :
  :
"layers" : [
    {
      "id" : 0,
      "name" : "Fluvial (20-1000 years)",
      "parentLayerId" : -1,
      "defaultVisibility" : true,
      "subLayerIds" : null,
      "minScale" : 0,
      "maxScale" : 0,
      "type" : "Raster Layer",
      "supportsDynamicLegends" : true,
      "legend" : [
        {
          "label" : "RP1000",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmB17/8/0+JQZo8jIwoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAADCgwSIkN8POQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        },
        {
          "label" : "RP500",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmBKRce/6fEoDkGsowoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAAAAcQU7gxM8XAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        },
        {
          "label" : "RP200",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmBovOf/KfEoNeJMowoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAAAsaQW6+46j0AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        },
        {
          "label" : "RP100",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmB5omv/1Ni0Mn5oowoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAAAzhgXP1djunAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        },
        {
          "label" : "RP50",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmBwdwH/1Ni0Nqv9owoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAABVoAYzC6UCvgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        },
        {
          "label" : "RP20",
          "imageData" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQElEQVQ4jWNhoDJgoZmBIqLx/ykx6M3rhYwoBlILsIwaSDFgodwIVDBqIOWAhQpmoIBRAykH8DCElWdUM5BaAACJZQbKJ7uUsQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
          "contentType" : "image/png",
          "groupId" : "0",
          "height" : 20,
          "width" : 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  :
  :
```